# Cannot get unit test to pass (httpRequest mock )

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, model-view-controller, mocking

I wrote a unit test thats failing:

```
        [Test]
    public async Task GetLogsPaged_Account_ExpectsSuccess()
    {
        //Arrange
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
        request.Setup(x => x.Scheme).Returns("https");
        request.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns(HostString.FromUriComponent("https://localhost:5001"));
        request.Setup(x => x.PathBase).Returns(PathString.FromUriComponent("/v1/customersupport-manager/logs/account/D4C88E3C-2848-400F-AB66-0DC3FAFFD24A?PageNumber=1&PageSize=5&DateFrom=2021-09-30%2012%3A30%3A13.413&DateTo=2021-09-30%2012%3A33%3A05.317"));

        List<LogEntry> logEntries = new List<LogEntry>() { new LogEntry { Id = 1 }, new LogEntry { Id = 2 } };
        PaginationFilter paginationFilter = new PaginationFilter { };
        LogEntryListFilter logEntryListFilter = new LogEntryListFilter { };

        var accountId = Guid.NewGuid();
        LogEntryPageResult logs = new LogEntryPageResult() { PagedRecords = logEntries };

        A.CallTo(() => logRepo.GetLogs(A<Guid>._, A<PaginationFilter>._, A<LogEntryListFilter>._)).Returns(logs);

        //Act
        var result = await svc.GetLogs(accountId, request.Object, paginationFilter, logEntryListFilter);

        //Assert
        result.ApplicationEvents[0].Code.Should().Be(ApplicationResponseCodes.System.OperationSucceed);
    }
```

When I debug the test I get a exception that says - {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}.

Which can only be var request because it's mocked. I'm not sure why I'm getting this exception when I've seen HttpRequest being mocked in other tests. Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit: I'm including the the line that fails in my code

```
 var uri = new Uri(request.GetDisplayUrl()); <- System.NullReference
```

But I have the url specified in my tests :

```
        request.Setup(x => x.Scheme).Returns("https");
        request.Setup(x => x.Host).Returns(HostString.FromUriComponent("https://localhost:5001"));
        request.Setup(x => x.PathBase).Returns(PathString.FromUriComponent("/v1/customersupport-manager/logs/account/D4C88E3C-2848-400F-AB66-0DC3FAFFD24A?PageNumber=1&PageSize=5"));
```

Comment: why do you think it is `requests`? Can't you debug it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I included what was failing in my test and @SomeBody it did not unfortunately. There is another test in my API that sets up _request_ in the same way and the test passes.

Comment: Can you just mock `request.GetDisplayUrl` ?

Answer (score 1):

`request.GetDisplayUrl` can't be mocked because it's a static extension method. As usual, the way to do this is to see what the extension method does and mock the underlying object.

In your case you haven't mocked enough. At the time of writing, this is enough for `GetDisplayUrl` to work:

```
var httpRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
httpRequest.SetupGet(req => req.Scheme).Returns("https");
httpRequest.SetupGet(req => req.Host).Returns(new HostString("localhost"));
httpRequest.SetupGet(req => req.PathBase).Returns("");
httpRequest.SetupGet(req => req.Path).Returns("/v1/myApi");
httpRequest.SetupGet(req => req.QueryString).Returns(QueryString.Empty);
```